# Delete all new files and folders besides user default folders

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, windows-registry, group-policy

Summary : I would need to delete all files and folders created/copied/moved into user's root profile. If someone creates a file it should automatically be deleted.

What I need :
User's are not to create folder or files in C:\Users\user

What I tried :
Del script clears everything. But I only want to delete off ALL except for the default user folders.
I tried the below script, it deletes most folders.

```
@ECHO OFF    
SETLOCAL    
SET "sourcedir=C:\Users\user"    
SET "keepdir=3D Objects"    
SET "keepdir=Contacts"    
SET "keepdir=Desktop"    
SET "keepdir=Documents"    
SET "keepdir=Downloads"    
SET "keepdir=Favorites"    
SET "keepdir=Links"    
SET "keepdir=Music"    
SET "keepdir=Pictures"   
SET "keepdir=Roaming"    
SET "keepdir=Saved Games"    
SET "keepdir=Searches"    
SET "keepdir=Videos"    
FOR /d %%a IN ("%sourcedir%\*") DO IF /i NOT "%%~nxa"=="%keepdir%" RD /S /Q "%%a"    
FOR %%a IN ("%sourcedir%\*") DO IF /i NOT "%%~nxa"=="%keepfile%" DEL "%%a"    
GOTO :EOF
```

[image: User folder]

Comment: I tried this,

for /d %%i in ("C:\Users\user") do if /i not "%%~nxi"=="Appdata" del /s /q "%%i"

But it is deleting Appdata instead.

Comment: Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\user" | Where-Object { $_.FullName -ne "C:\Users\user\3D Objects" } | Remove-Item -Recurse -Force

I tried this, but it "Remove-Item" , is there a keep-item?

Answer (score 1):

Try this in powershell:

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\User" | Where-Object {$_.Basename -notin @("3D objects","Contacts","Desktop","Downloads","Favorites","Links","Music","Pictures","Roaming","Saved Games","Searches","Videos")} | Remove-Item -Force
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to run silently in the background without user intervention?

Comment: `Start-Process Powershell.exe -ArgumentList "Filepath.ps1" -WindowsStyle Hidden` to run it silently and there is no `Keep-Item`.

Answer (score 0):

- For **[cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd)**/**[batch](/questions/tagged/batch)** files:

You need to compare each folder you have in your `%UserProfile%` with the default folders in `%SystemDrive%\Users\Default\` to perform the delete action when none match.

The path to Default folder in `%SystemDrive%\Users\Default\`, you can get by `reg query`:

```ps1
reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList"
```

So, I suggest a double `for` list, one `for` loop for each folder in its `%UserProfile%`, and one additional `for` loop for list the path of the Default user folders.

All you need to do is compare the currently listed folder in 1st `for` loop, with the Default list output from 2nd `for` loop using `find folder in 1st Loop` and delete if the operator `||` return non `0`...

Removes folders:

**Obs.: 1** This is for **`including`** those with **`hidden`** and/or **`system`** attributes:

```ps1
@echo off && setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "_keep_dir=3D\ Objects  Contacts  Searches"
set "_reg_key=HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList"

pushd "%UserProfile%" && for /f tokens^=* %%d in (
'^<con: dir /b /a:-a "%UserProfile%" ^|%__APPDIR__%findstr.exe /vi "%%~x !_keep_dir!"
')do for /f tokens^=3 %%i in ('%__APPDIR__%reg.exe query "!_reg_key!"^|find/i "Default"
')do <con: 2>nul dir /b /a:d /t "%%~i" | find /i "%%~d" >nul || echo\ rmDir /s /q "%%~d"

popd & endlocal & goto :eof
```

**Obs.: 2** You can put additional folder to prevent deletion in variable `_kepp_dir`, and for escaping space in folder name (like `3D Builder`) just ad `\`, e.g.: "`Folder With Space in Name`"

```ps1
set "_keep_dir=3D\ Objects  Contacts  Searches Folder\ With\ Space\ in\ Name"
```

**Obs.: 3**  For removes folders **excluding** those with **`hidden`** and/or **`system`** attributes:

```ps1
@echo off 

set "_keep=3D\ Objects Contacts Desktop Documents Downloads Favorites Links Music Pictures Roaming Saved\ Games Searches Videos"
cd /d "%UserProfile%" & for /d %%d in (*)do echo;%_keep% | %__APPDIR__%findstr.exe /vi "%%~d" >nul && rmDir /q /s "%%~d\."
```

---

- For **[powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell)** files:

For do the same in **[powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell)** and **`including`** those with **`hidden`** and/or **`system`** attributes:

```ps1
$RKey = Get-ItemPropertyValue 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList' 'Default'
$keep = (Get-ChildItem -Path $RKey -Force -Directory ).Name + 'Searches' + 'Contacts' + '3D Objects' + 'Add More Folder'

Get-ChildItem -Path "$env:USERPROFILE" -Directory -Force | Where-Object {$_.Name -notin @($keep)}  | Remove-Item -Force -Whatif
```

- By using aliases:

```ps1
$RKey = gpv 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList' 'Default'
$keep = (gci -Path $RKey -Force -di ).Name + 'Searches' + 'Contacts' + '3D Objects' + 'Add More Folder'

gci -Path "$env:USERPROFILE" -di -Force | ? {$_.Name -notin @($keep)} | rd -Force -Whatif
```

- You can test and if the results seems zOk to you, just remove **`-whatif`** for execution...

```ps1
Remove-Item -Force -Whatif
rd -Force -Whatif
```

---

- Some further reading:

  [√] **[Set](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html)**

  [√] **[For](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)**

  [√] **[For /F](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)**

  [√] **[For Loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for2.html)**

  [√] **[Conditional Execution || && ...](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)**

  [√] **[DelayedExpansion (SetLocal/EndLocal)](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)**

  [√] **[Where-Object | ? (Refer: `PowerShell`)](https://ss64.com/ps/where-object.html)**

  [√] **[Remove-Item | rd  (Refer: `PowerShell`)](https://ss64.com/ps/remove-item.htmll)**

  [√] **[Parameter -Whatif (Refer: `PowerShell`)](https://adamtheautomator.com/powershell-whatif/)**

  [√] **[Get-ItemPropertyValue | gpv (Refer: `PowerShell`)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-itempropertyvalue?view=powershell-7)**

  [√] **[Remove-Item with flag `WhatIf`  (Refer: `PowerShell`)](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/itops-talk-blog/powershell-basics-don-t-fear-hitting-enter-with-whatif/ba-p/353579)**

  [√] **[Concatenate items in variable list (Refer: `PowerShell`)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30802153/8177207)** By **[@Mathias R. Jessen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen)**

---

- For your comment: ***Is there a way to run silently in the background without user intervention?***

  [√] **[How to run a PowerShell script without displaying a window?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1802836/8177207)**

  [√] **[How to Assign a Logon Script to a User's Profile](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/324803/how-to-assign-a-logon-script-to-a-profile-for-a-local-user-in-windows#:%7E:text=In%20the%20console%20tree%2C%20expand,necessary%20of%20the%20logon%20script.)**

---